# Windows 8 minimum requirements?

Tags: windows-8

Currently I'm using Windows XP 32 bit on Intel Pentium dual core E5300 2.60 GHz processor 2 GB ram. Asus graphics card and Nvidia graphics driver.

I want to install Windows 8 pro can I install with this configuration?

Processor:

Intel Pentium E5300.
Specification Pentium Dual-Core CPU E5300 @ 2.60GHz.
Family 6 Extended
Family 6
Model 7
Extended Model 17
Instructions MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, Intel 64, NX, VMX.
Virtualization Supported, Disabled.
Hyperthreading Not supported.

Graphics:
NVIDIA GeForce GT 610.
Model GeForce GT 610.
GPU GF119.
Device ID 10DE-104A. Revision A2.
Subvendor ASUStek Computer Inc (1043).
DirectX Support 11.0
Driver version 6.14.13.1422 BIOS Version 75.19.55.00.02

Comment: Does your system meet the [requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/system-requirements) of `Windows 8.1`

Comment: I don't know is this processor does support for PAE, NX, and SSE2 . Someone tell me it will install or not.

Comment: I provided information about processor and what configuration I have.

Comment: There a reason you cannot look up if your process has those features on the Intel website yourself?  There are also tools that will provide that information.  Seems like you just want us to tell you the answer and you have not even attempted to determine what might be the case yourself.

Comment: Processor:
Intel Pentium E5300. 
Specification Pentium Dual-Core CPU E5300 @ 2.60GHz. Family 6 Extended 
Family 6 
Model 7 
Extended Model 17 
Instructions MMX, SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, Intel 64, NX, VMX. 
Virtualization Supported, Disabled. 
Hyperthreading Not supported.
Graphics: 
NVIDIA GeForce GT 610. 
Model GeForce GT 610. 
GPU GF119. 
Device ID 10DE-104A. Revision A2. 
Subvendor ASUStek Computer Inc (1043). 
DirectX Support 11.0 
Driver version 6.14.13.1422 BIOS Version 75.19.55.00.02

Answer (score 4):

- Windows 8.1 requirements [from Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/system-requirements):

> - Processor: 1 gigahertz (GHz) or faster with support for PAE, NX, and SSE2 (more info)
> - RAM: 1 gigabyte (GB) (32-bit) or 2 GB (64-bit)
> - Hard disk space: 16 GB (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit)
> - Graphics card: Microsoft DirectX 9 graphics device with WDDM driver
> - "Physical Address Extension (PAE), NX processor bit (NX), and Streaming SIMD Extensions 2 (SSE2) are features of the processor, and they're needed to run Windows 8.1."

Your 2GB of RAM should cut it, but I'd aim to go to at least 4GB. It's a cheap upgrade  in most cases these days.

You didn't mention your nVidia graphics adapter model, so you'll have to check with NVidia to confirm if it supports DirectX9 on your own.

- Specs for that processor [from Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/35300/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E5300-2M-Cache-2_60-GHz-800-MHz-FSB):

> - Instruction Set: 64-bit
> - Execute Disable Bit:  Yes

Let's go over the CPU requirements now...

You've got the 1GHZ CPU speed covered.

> "The NX bit, which stands for No-eXecute, is a technology used in CPUs... Intel markets the feature as the XD bit, for **eXecute Disable**." [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit)

So you're good there.

> "PAE gives 32-bit processors the ability to use more than 4 GB of physical memory on capable versions of Windows, and **is a prerequisite for NX**." [source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/what-is-pae-nx-sse2)

You have a 64-bit processor, *and* we've established NX is available on that processor, so you're good here too.

> "The AMD64 architecture supports the IA-32 as a compatibility mode and includes the SSE2 in its specification... The following IA-32 CPUs support SSE2: Intel NetBurst-based CPUs (Pentium 4, Xeon, Celeron, Pentium D, Celeron D)
>   " [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2#CPU_support)

So anything newer than a P4 definitely has the SSE2 extensions as a feature.

We can ensure this by checking the [full datasheet for that processor series](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/pentium/pentium-dual-core-e6000-e5000-datasheet.html) provided by Intel:

> The processors support all the existing **Streaming SIMD Extensions 2 (SSE2)**, Streaming SIMD Extensions 3 (SSE3), and Supplemental Streaming SIMD Extension 3 (SSSE3).

Comment: Are you able to comment on how Microsoft defines their minimum specs (what will work vs. what will provide satisfying speed in typical use)?